# Boole Simplifcation

Tags: boolean-computation

If you submit this to WA

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+and+b+and+c%29+or+%28not+a+and+not+b+and+not+c%29+or+%28not+a+and+b+and+not+c%29+or+%28a+and+not+b+and+not+c%29

and expand the Minimal Forms, it shows the Boole Normalform.

[image]

How is this normal form called in literature, because simply googling "Boole Normal form" is not giving me satisfying results and how to calculate this in mathematica directly?

Comment: See [`BooleanConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html), e.g., `Table[{fm, 
   BooleanConvert[(a && b && c) || (! a && ! b && ! c) || (! a && 
   b && ! c) || (a && ! b && ! c), fm]}, {fm, {"DNF", "CNF", "AND", "OR", "NAND",
     "NOR", "ESOP", "ANF", "BDT", "ITE"}}] // Grid`

Comment: @BobHanlon which of these is boole, boole is also not mentioned in the documentation of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html